# Parsing an f64 variable into a usize variable in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust

I have currently been dabbling in the Rust programming language and decided a good way to test my skills was to program an application that would find the median of any given list of numbers.

Eventually I got into the *Final stretch* of code and stumbled into a problem.

I needed to parse an f64 variable into a usize variable.

However, I don't know how to go about doing this (Wow what a surprise!).

Take a look at the second function, calc_med() in my code. The variable n2 is supposed to take n and parse it into a usize. The code is not finished yet, but if you can see any more problems with the code please let me know.

```
use std::io;
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref v1: Mutex<Vec<f64>> = Mutex::new(Vec::new());
}

fn main() {
    loop {
        println!("Enter: ");

        let mut inp: String = String::new();

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut inp).expect("Failure");
        
        let upd_inp: f64 = match inp.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => if inp.trim() == String::from("q") {
                break;
            } else if inp.trim() == String::from("d"){
                break
                {
                    println!("Done!");
                    calc_med();
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        };
        
        v1.lock().unwrap().push(upd_inp);
        v1.lock().unwrap().sort_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap());

        println!("{:?}", v1.lock().unwrap());
    }
}

fn calc_med() { // FOR STACKOVERFLOW: THIS FUNCTION
    let n: f64 = ((v1.lock().unwrap().len()) as f64 + 1.0) / 2.0;
    let n2: usize = n.to_usize().expect("Failure");

    let median: f64 = v1[n2];

    println!("{}", median)
}
```

Comment: what if your value is `1.5`? what should that be?

Comment: @DanielA.White What do you mean by that?

Comment: `usize` is an integer value, so it cannot represent fractional parts of a number. If you have a `f64` containing `1.5`, you can have a `usize` of `1` or `2` but nothing in between.

Comment: Ahh, I see. What I meant was that if a whole number is entered, the value would be changed to a usize.

Comment: You divide by two, so if the vector length is even (so length + 1 is odd), `n` will have a `.5`.

Comment: Why are you using a global static for this?

Comment: @PitaJ Yeah, if the vector length is even it will have a decimal place, but I plan on handlin g that later in the code since it is unfinished. I am also using a Global Static because I prefer using Global Variables for stuff like this.

Comment: The only way to convert `f64` to `usize` right now is with `as`. But I question whether you need the `f64` in the first place. Just use integer arithmetic instead, since you'll have to handle the odd case separately anyways.

Comment: I could, although I don't think it would work with median calculation. I will do some more digging.

Comment: Nitpick: you don't need `lazy_static` for `Mutex`, `Mutex::new()` is now const fn. And anyway, prefer `once_cell` to `lazy_static`.